# Jinja variable is undefined

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I'm trying to build the hosts file on my servers using salt. In some of the servers, the eth0 network interface has the inet set and in some others is the bond0 interface.

In the init.sls i have:

```
 /etc/hosts:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://configs/etc/hosts/hostsfile
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 644
    - template: jinja
    - context:
      {% for host, interface in salt['mine.get']('*', 'network.interfaces').items() %}
        {% if interface['bond0'].has_key('inet') %}
      ip: {{ salt['network.interfaces']()['bond0']['inet'][0]['address'] }}
        {% else %}
      ip: {{ salt['network.interfaces']()['eth0']['inet'][0]['address'] }}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      hostname: {{ salt['network.get_hostname']() }}
```

And in my hosts file that is set above in the "- source", i have:

```
{{ ip }}  {{ hostname }}
```

Then, when i run a state.highstate from the salt master, i get an error saying:

> SaltRenderError: Jinja variable 'ip' is undefined; line 97

It seems like that the salt function that retrieves the network interface, does not work when it is inside the jinja for loop(or i'm doing something wrong). 
I'm saying that because last line where it returns the hostname, works just fine.

What am i doing wrong here ? I'm suspecting that the if condition is not met and thus the "ip" variable never gets assigned a value.

Thank you,

Comment: Note

The defaults and context arguments require extra indentation (four spaces instead of the normal two) in order to create a nested dictionary.  you tried this?

Comment: look in the documentation of file.managed

Comment: @tudoricc thanks for you reply. I just tried what you said, but still the same. I'm thinking that it has to do more with the "if" condition

Comment: it shouldn't,the else branch should work just as well

Comment: I really think the for is somehow wrong,why not try getting the interfaces using grains?look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30939758/1976942

Comment: I find this approach simpler and realiable for future uses

Comment: @tudoric using grains was easier. I ended up removing the for loop and if condition, and just doing:
    ip: {{ grains.ipv4[0] }}
But the downside of that is that you have to specify the [0] otherwise it returns also the 127.0.0.1 IP
And another downside with this approach is that you can't specify the interface you want, in case one want a specific interface.

Comment: have you tried getting the interface through the key value?                      `{%- for iface in grains['ip_interfaces'].keys() %}`